# Export with Generic interface and constraint does not match import

Tags: c#, mef

my interface and class looks like the following:

```
public interface ITree<T> where T : IComparable
```

A class which implements the interface:

```
public class Tree<T> : ITree<T> where T : IComparable
```

I want to import all classes which implement ITree where T: IComparable with ITree

I tried many diffrent exports like:

```
registrationITreeBuilder
    .ForTypesMatching(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(ITree<>).Name) != null)
    .Export<ITree<int>>();

registrationITreeBuilder
    .ForTypesMatching(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(ITree<>).Name) != null)
    .Export(b=>b.AsContractType(typeof(ITree<int>));

registrationITreeBuilder
    .ForTypesDerivedFrom(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(ITree<>).Name) != null)
    .Export<ITree<int>>();
```

and so on.

But all exports I tried did not match for the import:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<ITree<int>> TreeInstances { get; set; }
```

How must the export defined to match the above import?

Comment: Not sure what library you're using but it looks like you're trying to match `ITree<>` to `IEnumerable<ITree<int>>` ?

Comment: yes, the interface ITree<T> where T : IComparable is created by myself. The implemention will be done by thirdparties.